# How to animate back function

Tags: jquery

```
$('.box').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px',
        top: '-70px'
    }, 500),
    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: '30px',
            height: '30px',
            top: '0'
        });
    };
});
```

In this case as hover expand box as mouseout bring it back...But animate call back doesn't work..where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want like this, just change the operation for it.

Js

```
 $('.box').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px',
        top: '-70px'
    }, 500);
    },

    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: '30px',
            height: '30px',
            top: '0'
        });
 });
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/HCP3L/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.box').hover(        
    function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px',
        top: '-70px'
    }, 500);
    },

    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: '30px',
            height: '30px',
            top: '0'
        });
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/8pDqt/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.box').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: '200px',
        height: '200px',
        top: '-70px',
        done: function () { //A function to be called when the animation completes
            $(this).stop().animate({
                width: '30px',
                height: '30px',
                top: '0'
            });
        };
    }, 500);
});
```

Read [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "*where am I wrong*": You have just misplaced a `}`.

Your code should be:

```
$('.box').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: '200px',
            height: '200px',
            top: '-70px'
        }, 500);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            width: '30px',
            height: '30px',
            top: '0'
        });
    }
);
```

You tried to enclose one function inside another. That is not how the `hover` syntax is. The two functions for `enter` and `leave` must be seperated with a comma and no overlap.

The `}` from your last line is moved up before the second `function()` starts. This works, when I try it. And that was the only mistake.